# Python threading - blocking operation - terminate execution

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python program like this:

```
from threading import Thread

def foo():
  while True:
    blocking_function() #Actually waiting for a message on a socket

def run():
  Thread(target=foo).start()

run()
```

This program does not terminate with `KeyboardInterrupt`, due to the main Thread exiting before a Thread running `foo()` has a chance to terminate. I tried keeping the main thread alive with just running `while True` loop after calling `run()` but that also doesn't exit the program (`blocking_function()` just blocks the thread from running I guess, waits for the message). Also tried catching KeyboardInterrupt exception in main thread and call `sys.exit(0)` - same outcome (I would actually expect it to kill the thread running `foo()`, but apparently it doesn't)

Now, I could simply timeout the execution of `blocking_function()` but that's no fun. Can I unblock it on `KeyboardInterrupt` or anything similar?

Main goal: Terminate the program with blocked thread on `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little bit of a workaround, but you could use `thread` instead of `threading`. This is not really advised, but if it suits you and your program, why not.

You will need to keep your program running, otherwise the thread exits right after `run()`

```
import thread, time

def foo():
  while True:
    blocking_function() #Actually waiting for a message on a socket

def run():
  thread.start_new_thread(foo, ())

run()
while True:
  #Keep the main thread alive
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It does terminate with Ctrl+C now. But why doest `thread` do that and not `threading`??